# How to find 'lost' code with a constant in Git

Tags: git, version-control

Once upon a time, one bad guy had deleted a constant from the source code managed through our Git repository.

Nobody has noticed this for a loooong time.... until now.

Yet I want to figure out in which commit this constant is gone, and who the bad guy is.

I only know the constant's name was `FOOBAR`.

Is there some better approach as `git blame --reverse`?

Comment: who was the bad guy?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This will list all commits that added or removed the string FOOBAR from any file:

```
git log --all -p -SFOOBAR
```

Comment: fatal: unrecognized argument: --patch

Comment: Holy hell, really?  How old is your Git?  Try with `-p` instead of `--patch`.

Comment: Odd, 1.7.1 should have `--patch`.

Answer (score 0):

[git log](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) like `git log -- path/to/file/with/constant` should get you all the commits that have ever touched that file.  If the file doesn't change that often and your team is in the habit of writing good commit messages then that should get you started.

Once you find the revision where it dissapeared you then have your offender.

Another option would be [git bisect](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bisect.html) to search for the offending commit using a binary search pattern if the file does change a lot.  Something along the lines of:

```
$ git bisect start
$ git bisect bad
$ git bisect good <known-good-rev>
$ fgrep -Hn "FOOBAR" file
# Ah it is good!
$ git bisect good
$ fgrep -Hn "FOOBAR" file
# Ah it is bad!
$ git bisect bad
```

Continue following the instructions until you've found the revision that introduced the error.  Read the [man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bisect.html) for more detailed instructions.  Another good resource to read would be the [relevant section of Pro Git](http://progit.org/book/ch6-5.html).

Good luck.